# Retracted Close Vote Doesn't Allow You to Flag As Duplicate

Tags: support, flags, retracted-close-votes

Recently I chose to vote to close a question but then found out it was actually a duplicate.

I realise when you have voted to close for one reason you cannot pick another once your vote is retracted but I assumed that I would be able to flag as duplicate once the close vote was retracted, it appears I was wrong.

Why is this? What is the best way to go about reporting this question as a duplicate without flagging for Moderator attention?

Comment: flag as duplicate == vote to close

Comment: @CodyGray >>> True

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A duplicate vote is still a close vote so that explains why you can't vote again after you retracted your vote.

You can leave a comment on the post with a link to the duplicate. Other members with flags or votes will start the duplicate close voting/flagging for you.

If you have no objection to the interference of a chat room you could drop in the [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) room and leave a cv-pls there, indicating both the question and the duplicate target. Here is [one example](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/41570?m=27815164#27815164) of such request. The regulars in the room will help you out.

Comment: I assumed flags and close reason where different, I didn't realise that a *Flag As Duplicate* is just the same as *Close As Duplicate*. I added a comment so the duplicate is linked at least.

Comment: Yeah, it just depends on reputation, above 3K your flags for duplicate and close becomes close votes.

Comment: The bad UX of having two access points to the same feature, but with different labels, strikes again.